# Peripheral illumination correction value

Tags: canon, software, vignetting, lens-correction, canon-dpp

In Canon Digital Photo Professional one can apply Peripheral Illumination Correction if a profile for specific lens is available. The value is adjustable between 0 and 120.

Did anyone figure out what those values mean exactly? I could not find an exact answer in the Canon documentation. When restoring "default" values, they depend on the lens and aperture selected. I have a feeling that the default value leaves some vignetting. From the other hand, value of 100 seems to strong. What value should one apply to achieve uniform illumination across the whole frame?

Comment: This is something I always found strange - and Nikon does something similar. If they have a profile and EXIF information is saved correctly, correction should be exact unless there is major sample variation.

Comment: The "default" value is dependent upon the in camera settings at the time the photo was taken. What numerical value are you getting as the 'default' value? 100%? 0%? Was in camera PIC turned on or off?

Comment: Was a profile for the *exact* lens in question loaded into the camera when the photo was taken? Most Canon cameras come preloaded with a few common lenses, but profiles for many other lenses must be downloaded and installed in the camera using *EOS Utility* for the in-camera correction to be enabled for a specific lens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scale of 0 to 120 is a *percentage* value. At 100% the amount of correction should in theory be exactly enough to equalize brightness across the entire field of view if the photograph was taken of a uniformly bright field.

Depending on the particular lens in question, the 'compact' lens profile loaded into the camera at the time the image is shot may or may not be detailed enough to actually accomplish this at every focal length and aperture combination. When any Canon raw image file is first opened in *Digital Photo Professional* the in-camera settings used when the photo was taken are applied by default (unless the user has changed that setting in *DPP*). So whatever values were used by the camera are what *DPP* starts with. Even if *Peripheral Illumination Correction* was turned on in the camera when the photo was taken, if the camera did not have a profile loaded for the specific lens used, the default value will probably be '0'.

Sometimes a photographer may want some light fall-off in the corners but not as much as what the lens gives without any correction, so the option is there to adjust the value anywhere from no correction (0) to full correction (100) to more than full correction (120).

One can presume that the 120% setting is available for cases where the entire field of view of the scene was not uniformly illuminated when the photo was taken but the photographer wants to make it appear uniform in the end result. One example would be a wide angle photo taken using the camera's popup flash which tends to be brighter at the center and dimmer on the edges and in the corners.